# How to assign values to row of a matrix when matrix name is a character string

Tags: r

I want to create several matrixes and assign values which are obtained through the function to the specific rows automatically. I'll give example of what I've tried so far:

```
EXAMPLE1<-matrix(ncol=4, nrow=16)
EXAMPLE2<-matrix(ncol=4, nrow=16)
EXAMPLE3<-matrix(ncol=4, nrow=16)
EXAMPLE4<-matrix(ncol=4, nrow=16)


for(i in 1:16){
  for(j in 1:4){
    paste0("EXAMPLE",j, "[",i,",","]")<- c(1:4)
  }
}
```

and

```
for(i in 1:16){
  for(j in 1:4){
    get(paste0("EXAMPLE",j)[i,]<- c(1:4)
  }
}
```

but  *"target of assignment expands to non-language object"* is returned. So I tried

```
for(i in 1:16){
  for(j in 1:4){
    assign(paste0("EXAMPLE",j, "[",i,",","]"), c(1:4))
  }
}
```

This does not return error, but values are not written into matrix.

*At first matrixes are empty*

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

*and after one loop is performed (i=1) I expext all EXAMPLE matrixes to have 1 row filled (and after second - second row filled, so that when loop ends I would have EXAMPLE matrix full of numbers.).*

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

The point is though, i do not how to assign value to the matrix row, because I pass matrix name by paste function. How to assign values to a specific row in a matrix if I want to put its name as character string? Any help would be wonderful. Thanks

...Edition...
I am sorry that I am not very clear. As I mentioned, I want to write result of a function (which happens to have same number of columns as my matrix) into matrix row. Each row would take result from function applied to different observation. I want to apply several functions to same variable so I have several matrixes for results of the different function (which differ in column numbers and have different names). The way I numbered and named matrixes is the easiest to keep track of results and later compare them. Above I gave just an example of problem which is that I cannot assign value to a row of matrix because I give name of matrix as string (and I do that because otherwise there would be quite a lot of numbering to do). So in general I want to be able to do

```
EXAMPLEj[i,]<-SomeFunctionResult
```

Where j goes 1 to 10 or some other numbers

Thats why I use loop and `paste0("EXAMPLE", j)` to generate names of matrixes and i to denote which observation for function to use and in which row to put the result. Matrixes are already created, but I found no way to pass results to row of the matrix.

I am new at R (and programming) so it is possible I've chosen the worst way possible to solve this and that list or arrays would be much easier to use. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Can you give the result of what you want?

Comment: Are you trying to create a matrix with `1,2,3,4` on the columns and repeat it for all the rows ?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want tod do ! Try to show what do you want to do with one matrix. Then I think it is better to put your variables in a list and use `do.call` or `lapply` to generalize what do you do for a single matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Put the individual matrices into a list:

```
EXAMPLE <- list(EXAMPLE1, EXAMPLE2, EXAMPLE3, EXAMPLE4)
```

Then, simply access the matrices in this list by index:

```
for(i in 1:16){
  for(j in 1:4){
    EXAMPLE[[j]][i,] <- c(1:4)
  }
}
```

The list can also be named, and accessed by the names:

```
EXAMPLE <- list(EXAMPLE1=EXAMPLE1, EXAMPLE2=EXAMPLE2,
                EXAMPLE3=EXAMPLE3, EXAMPLE4=EXAMPLE4)
EXAMPLE[['EXAMPLE1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to iterate over your different matricies, 
and then to iterate over each row in the given matrix.

If the task is iteration, you should think of using lists  -- or if iterating over matricies, arrays

```
# create an array of 5 (five) 16x4 matricies: 
EXAMPLE <- array(dim=c(16, 4, 5))  # i changed your four examples to 5, to be clear

# Have a look at the 5 matricies: 
EXAMPLE

# TO SELECT A SINGLE MATRIX, SAY EXAMPLE2: 
EXAMPLE[,, 2]  # note the two commas
```

Then if you want to use loops to iterate (not generally recomended, but it is simple)

```
for (k in 1:5)  # again, using 5 to distinguish
  for (i in 1:16)
    EXAMPLE[i, , k] <- i* (1:4)

EXAMPLE
```

---

You can also use `apply`, where the `MARGIN` argument corresponds to the dimensions you set. 
(ie, in this case, `MARGIN==1` is for rows, `2` for columns and `3` for the specific matrix)

For example,   `apply(EXAMPLE, MARGIN=3, FUN=someFunction)`   applies the function `someFunction` to each of the matricies, one at a time. 
In other words, it is iterating over each matrix, much like the `k`- `for` loop above

Thus, your two nested loops above can be put into a single line of code:

```
# note the empty [ ] to maintain array properties
EXAMPLE[ ] <- apply(EXAMPLE, 3, function(M) 1:ncol(M) %x% 1:nrow(M))

# have a look at the results
EXAMPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to show the differences between two matrices?

```
> EXAMPLE2 <- matrix(ncol=4, nrow=16, sample(1:10, 4*16, replace=TRUE))

> EXAMPLE1 <- EXAMPLE2
> EXAMPLE1[3,4] <- 99

> diffs <- ifelse(EXAMPLE1!=EXAMPLE2, EXAMPLE1, "")
> diffs
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [2,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [3,] ""   ""   ""   "99"
 [4,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [5,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [6,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [7,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [8,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
 [9,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[10,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[11,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[12,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[13,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[14,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[15,] ""   ""   ""   ""  
[16,] ""   ""   ""   ""  

> print(diffs, quote=FALSE)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]                    
 [2,]                    
 [3,]                99  
 [4,]                    
 [5,]                    
 [6,]                    
 [7,]                    
 [8,]                    
 [9,]                    
[10,]                    
[11,]                    
[12,]                    
[13,]                    
[14,]                    
[15,]                    
[16,]
```